# CORS for Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, cors

I have a web app deployed to a **non Firebase hosting** service, made with NextJS.
I am using Firebase Cloud Functions in addition to this. In particular I am using callable functions. The code below shows my `index.js` file in the `functions` directory.

```js
// index.js
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()
const db = admin.firestore()

const function1 = require('./src/function1')

exports.function1 = functions
    .region('us-east1')
    .https.onCall((data, context) => {
      return function1.handler(data, context, db)
    })


// /src/function1.js
exports.handler = (data, context, db) => {
  // code
}
```

The function itself uses the `context` parameter and the `db` parameter to make a call to `firestore` and add/delete records as necessary.
The function builds correctly and works perfectly when emulated locally.

However, when invoked on my hosted web app, I receive a CORS error.

The only method I have found after searching stackoverflow and the document is the following:

- [CORS Limitations](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/write-http-functions#cors-limitations) - which links to the below
- [Allow unauthorised access](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#after_deployment)

Doing the above did solve my issue but now will allow calls to the function by any user including those that are unauthorised.
I am concerned about security and would like to know either

1. how to allow unauthorised invocations but exit the function if the user is not authorised (through the `context` parameter that is automatically populated after the callable function is invoked)
2. allow a specific URI to invoke my cloud functions, e.g. `https://www.mywebsite.com`

Help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

---

***Edit:***
Based on comments, here is the requested further information:

- I am using Firebase auth
- The CORS error is below:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://us-east1-(projectid).cloudfunctions.net/function1' from origin 'https://(projectid).vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

- I did have another look at what the context parameter provides in terms of the auth context, but am not sure how to block out a non-logged in user as the rest of the security should be handled by firestore rules.
- The code responsible for invoking the function client side is below:

```js
import { functions } from './FirebaseConfig'
// ^ the above will import 
// export const firebase = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
// export const functions = getFunctions(firebase, 'us-east1')

const function1 = httpsCallable(functions, 'function1')

// This is then called via a button onclick handler
<button             
  onClick={() => {
    function1({
      // data
    })
      .then(result => {
        // handle result
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // handle errors 
      })
  }}
>
  Invoke Function
</button>
```

---

***Further edits:***

- Ah yes, I can use the auth.uid property to check if they are logged in. "Firebase Admin SDK (which you will use with Cloud Functions) will bypass all security rules you have configured" - since this is the case, is there any possibility that a user may spoof a request if they are to guess someone's uid - I am talking theoretically.
- Accessing the function via the browser through a `GET` method returns a status code of `400` and error message of `Bad request`

Comment: Do you use Firebase authentication?

Comment: _I receive a CORS error._. What CORS error? Also, please note that CORS is no substitute for server-side authorisation.

Comment: Please add the portion of your code that invokes the function from the client-side/next code - especially because you are using the `us-east1` region instead of the `us-central1` region. HTTP 404 (function) Not Found errors will often be masked as CORS errors.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec, I have added an edit to the main post answering your comments.

Comment: @aabdulahad Since you use Firebase Auth you can check that `context.auth.uid` is not `null`. It means that the user calling the Callable function is authenticated. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#write_and_deploy_the_callable_function

Comment: What happens when you visit the function's URL directly in your browser?

Comment: "as the rest of the security should be handled by firestore rules" - that applies to client-side code. Code that uses the Firebase Admin SDK (which you will use with Cloud Functions) will bypass all security rules you have configured.

Comment: Please see further edit thank you.

Comment: I've got the same problem. On my other projects never had this problem even without firebase auth front side, but now can't call my functions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before a CORS request is sent by a browser (e.g. a `GET` request), the browser first sends an `OPTIONS` request.

You need to handle this case, and tell the browser the request is OK to make.

You can do this in your function like using [onRequest()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/firebase-functions.https#httpsonrequest) and the [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) library.

```
const cors = require('cors');
const handler = cors({origin: true});
...
exports.myCorsFunction = functions
    .https.onRequest((req, res) => {
      cors()(req, res, () => {
        return res.json({status: 'ok'});
      });
});
```

Here's a nice [article](https://akhromieiev.com/enabling-cors-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase/) with more examples.